# Jest + SonarQube - Report not being imported

Tags: node.js, typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, ts-jest

I'm running sonar-scanner on my NodeJS + Typescript app, as well as using Jest for the unit test. I'm able to see the report on the console, displaying the coverage for each of the modules created. I then looked up how to integrate Jest with Sonarqube using jest-sonar-reporter, which is generating the report.xml as expected.

I'm having trouble getting the coverage which I get running jet --coverage to be displayed in sonarqube.

**This is the structure of my project**

```
├── babel.config.js
├── coverage
│   ├── clover.xml
│   ├── coverage-final.json
│   ├── lcov.info
│   ├── lcov-report
│   └── test-reporter.xml
├── Dockerfile
├── ecs-meta.json
├── Jenkinsfile
├── nodemon.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── properties
│   ├── application-dev.json
│   ├── application-prd.json
│   ├── application-tst.json
│   └── application-uat.json
├── README.md
├── sonar-project.properties
├── sonarqube.ts
├── src
│   ├── configs
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── StoreController.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── consul.model.ts
│   │   └── UserModel.ts
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── StoreRoutes.ts
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── __mocks__
│   │   │   └── Repository.ts
│   │   └── Repository.ts
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   └── index.test.ts
│   │   └── utils
│   │       └── ExpressResponseMock.ts
│   └── typings.d.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "sonar": "npx sonar-scanner",
    "test": "jest --collectCoverage",
    "start": "echo \"== DO NOT USE START SCRIPT FOR PRODUCTION ==\" && nodemon",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "tslint --project ./tsconfig.json --config ./tslint.json",
    "review": "cross-env CI=true && npm run lint && npm run build",
    "prettify": "prettier --write ./src/**/*.ts"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "src/config/*"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "coverage",
    "reportFile": "test-reporter.xml",
    "indent": 4
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "npm run review"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts}": [
      "npm run lint",
      "npm run prettify"
    ]
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 110
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/consul": "^0.23.34",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^13.5.1",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "consul": "^0.37.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "node-vault": "^0.9.20",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "vault-auth-aws": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.9",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.7.0",
    "supertest": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0"
  }
}
```

**My sonar-project.properties**

```
#sonar.organization=YOUR-ORGANISATION-KEY

# relative paths to source directories. More details and properties are described
# in https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/
sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.in
sonar.projectKey=**

sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.test.inclusions=src/**/*.spec.js,src/**/*.spec.jsx,src/**/*.test.js,src/**/*.test.jsx,src/**/*.test.ts,src/**/*.test.tsx

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=./coverage/test-reporter.xml
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

These are outputs for both jest --coverage, and sonar-scanner:

**$jest --coverage**

```
PASS  src/test/controllers/index.test.ts
  Get 
    ✓ Get Stores (12 ms)

  console.log
    Starting lookup for store ""

      at Object.getStores (src/controllers/StoreController.ts:4:11)

  console.info
    Success retrieving store based on "" details!

      at then.result (src/controllers/StoreController.ts:7:15)

-------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                     | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                |   17.24 |        0 |   33.33 |   17.24 |                   
 src                     |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
  index.ts               |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 8-28              
  typings.d.ts           |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
 src/controllers         |   66.67 |      100 |   66.67 |   66.67 |                   
  StoreController.ts     |   66.67 |      100 |   66.67 |   66.67 | 11-12             
 src/models              |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
  UserModel.ts           |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
  consul.model.ts        |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
 src/routes              |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 |                   
  StoreRoutes.ts         |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 3-5               
  index.ts               |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 | 5-14              
 src/services            |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
  Repository.ts          |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 3-16              
 src/test/utils          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  ExpressResponseMock.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.995 s
Ran all test suites.
```

As can be seen below, it says that the coverage report was found and parsed successfully, but I do not see it on Sonar dashboard:

```
INFO: Parsing /mnt/86da7b30-23bc-4ecb-a95e-bbeaecd50c7d/Documents/work/projects/stores/coverage/test-reporter.xml
INFO: Imported test execution data for 1 files
INFO: Sensor Generic Test Executions Report (done) | time=16ms
```

**This is the content of the report:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testExecutions version="1">
    <file path="/mnt/86da7b30-23bc-4ecb-a95e-bbeaecd50c7d/Documents/work/projects/stores/src/test/controllers/index.test.ts">
        <testCase name="Get  Get Stores" duration="12"/>
    </file>
</testExecutions>
```

**$sonar-scanner -X**

[OUTPUT HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mj6Utg8lKPEM39EYZE36NK8HpBiwlce_/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT 1**
SonarQube version - The version is - Community EditionVersion 7.9.1 (build 27448)

Comment: which's sonarqube version are you using ? this just affect on SonarQube 6.2+ feature.

Comment: The version is - Community EditionVersion 7.9.1 (build 27448)

Comment: sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info, as you don't have .js files in your project

Comment: What I see for my configuration which is same like yours: `WARN: Could not resolve 103 file paths in [/mnt/ramdisk/agents/agent12/work/dbe8ad65d6f5738a/./coverage/lcov.info], first unresolved path: src/app/app.component.html`, but this is different coverage report directly from `jest --coverage`, whereas the `test-reporter.xml` generated by *jest-sonar-reporter* is being imported - I am confused here